# Python: add incremental ID in fasta header

Tags: python, header, fasta

I try to create a multi fasta from a .csv file with a incremental ID in the header. But my script don't works well. Any suggestion?

```
M=open('/home/anna/Scrivania/db_mat/matk_2db_c.csv','r')
M_out=open('/home/anna/Scrivania/db_mat/db_matk_bronx.fas', 'w')

for i in range[1,92]:
    num = "m" + str(i)
for line in M:
    line1=line.split(',')
    ID = line1[0]
    SEQ = line1[1]
    seq =line1[2]
M_out.write('>'+ num +'_' +ID +'_'+ SEQ +'\n' + seq )

M.close()
M_out.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want range[1,92]?

Comment: `range[1,92]:` *probably* should be `range(1,92):`

Comment: Could you provide sample-data and clarify the changes you want to make as well as the errors you get? The people here can only help you from what you give them. one general hint: for processing of csv I recomend using the the csv module (type import csv and on the next line help(csv) for the fasta generation biopython might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,line in enumerate(M,1):
    num = "m"+str(i)
    line1=line.split(',')
    ID = line1[0]
    SEQ = line1[1]
    seq =line1[2]
    M_out.write(...)
```

this just enumerates through the lines and gives you an index from 1..N where N is the number of lines

before you were iterating over all the nums, so by the time you got to `for line in M` num would equal "m91" for all lines